# How to retrieve and view the elements from the NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying some examples from the book "Objective C for Dummies". I tried to retrieve the elements with this code below but in vain. All are considered as Objects in the NSMutableArray. But I don't know how to retrieve the elements using the objects.

### main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BudObj.h"
#import "Transaction.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        Budget* europeBudget=[Budget new];
        NSMutableArray *transactions=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
        [europeBudget createBudget:1000.00 withExchangeRate:1.2500];
        Transaction* aTransaction;
        aTransaction = [Transaction new];
        for(int n=1;n<2;n++){
                aTransaction = [[Transaction alloc] init];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:cash];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
                [aTransaction release];
        }

        int n=1;
        while (n<3) {
                aTransaction = [[Transaction alloc]init];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:credit];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
                [aTransaction release];
                n++;
        }

        do{
                aTransaction = [[Transaction alloc]init];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:cash];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
                [aTransaction release];
                n++;
        }while (n<=3);

        NSLog(@"\nNumber of elements in an array:%i",[transactions count]);
        int c;
        c=[transactions count];
        NSLog(@"\nThe Elements are:\n");
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
                NSLog(@"%@",[transactions objectAtIndex:i]);
        }

        for(Transaction *aaTransaction in transactions){
         switch ([aTransaction returnType]) {
                case cash:
                        [europeBudget spendDollars:[aaTransaction returnAmount]];
                        break;
                case credit:
                        [europeBudget changeForeignCurrency:[aaTransaction returnAmount]];
                        break;
                default:
                        break;
         }
        }
        [transactions release];
        [europeBudget release];

        return 0;
}
```

### BudObj.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface 
Budget : NSObject {

        float  exchangeRate;
        double budget;
        double exchangeTransaction;

}

- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
- (void) spendDollars: (double) dollars;
- (void) changeForeignCurrency: (double) foreignCurrency;

@end
```

### BudObj.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BudObj.h"
#import "Transaction.h"

@implementation Budget

- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate{
        budget = aBudget;
        exchangeRate = anExchangeRate;
}


- (void) spendDollars:(double)dollars{
    budget = budget - dollars;
        NSLog(@"Converting %0.2f US Dollars into Foreign Currency leaves $%0.2f",dollars,budget);
}

- (void) changeForeignCurrency:(double)foreignCurrency{
    exchangeTransaction = foreignCurrency * exchangeRate;
        budget = budget - exchangeTransaction;
        NSLog(@"Charging %0.2f in Foreign Currency leaves $%0.2f",foreignCurrency,budget);
}

@end
```

### Transaction.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

typedef enum{cash,credit} transactionType;

@interface Transaction : NSObject {

        transactionType type;
        double amount;

}

-(void)createTransaction:(double)theAmount ofType:(transactionType)theType;
-(double)returnAmount;
-(transactionType)returnType;

@end
```

### Transaction.m

```
#import "Transaction.h"

@implementation Transaction

-(void)createTransaction:(double)theAmount ofType:(transactionType)theType{

        type=theType;
        amount=theAmount;

}

    -(double)returnAmount{

            return amount;

    }

    -(transactionType)returnType{

            return type;

    }

@end
```

### Output

```
The Elements are:
2011-04-15 18:12:11.039 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] <Transaction: 0x10010c950> //Could not retreive the data from the array it's showing up some address
2011-04-15 18:12:11.039 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] <Transaction: 0x100104fe0> //
2011-04-15 18:12:11.040 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] <Transaction: 0x100106c60> //
2011-04-15 18:12:11.040 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] <Transaction: 0x100106d00> //
2011-04-15 18:12:11.041 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] Converting 100.00 US Dollars into Foreign Currency leaves $900.00
2011-04-15 18:12:11.041 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] Converting 100.00 US Dollars into Foreign Currency leaves $800.00
2011-04-15 18:12:11.041 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] Converting 200.00 US Dollars into Foreign Currency leaves $600.00
2011-04-15 18:12:11.042 BudObj.m[2180:a0f] Converting 300.00 US Dollars into Foreign Currency leaves $300.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Transaction* transaction in transactions) {
   //do stuff here, or just print the object with something like the code below
   NSLog(@"Transaction:  %@", transaction);
}
```

Of course, when you have code like this:

```
[aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:credit];
[transactions addObject:aTransaction];
```

...you are not actually storing the newly created transaction in the array.  You are just storing the variable `aTransaction` multiple times.  You may have better luck with something like:

```
Transaction* nextTransaction = [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:credit];
[transactions addObject:nextTransaction];
```

**Edit:**

You may have more luck with:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BudObj.h"
#import "Transaction.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        Budget* europeBudget=[[Budget alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *transactions=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
        [europeBudget createBudget:1000.00 withExchangeRate:1.2500];
        Transaction* aTransaction = nil;
        for(int n=1;n<2;n++){
                //this adds 1 transaction to the array
                aTransaction = [[[Transaction alloc] init] autorelease];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:cash];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
        }

        int n=1;
        while (n<3) {
                //this adds 2 transactions to the array
                aTransaction = [[[Transaction alloc] init] autorelease];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:credit];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
                n++;
        }

        do{
                //this adds 1 transaction to the array
                aTransaction = [[[Transaction alloc] init] autorelease];
                [aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:cash];
                [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
                n++;
        }while (n<=3);

        //there should be 4 elements in the array now
        NSLog(@"\nNumber of elements in an array:%i",[transactions count]);  
        int c;
        c=[transactions count];
        NSLog(@"\nThe Elements are:\n");
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
                Transaction* trans = [transactions objectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"Transaction %d:  %@; type=%d, amount=%f", i, trans, [trans returnType], [trans returnAmount]);
        }

        for(Transaction *aaTransaction in transactions){
         switch ([aTransaction returnType]) {
                case cash:
                        [europeBudget spendDollars:[aaTransaction returnAmount]];
                        break;
                case credit:
                        [europeBudget changeForeignCurrency:[aaTransaction returnAmount]];
                        break;
                default:
                        break;
         }
        }
        [transactions release];
        [europeBudget release];

        return 0;
}
```

The address that you see in your output doesn't mean that the program couldn't find the `Transaction` in the array.  In fact, it means the exact opposite.  The address is the address in memory of your `Transaction` instance.  The reason it gets printed as an address is because that is the default behavior when printing an `NSObject` instance.  Your class is not overriding this default behavior, so you get the memory address when you print it.

If you want to override this default behavior, you can do something like:

```
#import "Transaction.h"

@implementation Transaction

    //override the 'description' method to change how your object prints
    -(NSString*)description {
        NSString* friendlyType = theType == cash ? @"cash" : @"credit";
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Transaction:  type=%@, amount=%f", friendlyType, amount];
    }

    -(void)createTransaction:(double)theAmount ofType:(transactionType)theType{
        type=theType;
        amount=theAmount;
    }

    -(double)returnAmount{
            return amount;
    }

    -(transactionType)returnType{
            return type;
    }

@end
```

Comment: I tried this also.I'm getting some address printed out as output.

Comment: @Beata Jane - that is probably the address of your object instances.  If you provide some details about what fields/properties exist on a `Transaction` object we can provide some better examples of how to print them in a meaningful way.

Comment: @aroth-I have edited the code and have given the full program above.please go through it.

Comment: @Beata Jane - Sorry for the delay, I've updated my answer.  Hope it helps clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that you're outputting your object as an integer (`i`) in your `NSLog`. Instead you should use `@`.

Another issue is that objects in Objective-C are reference types. That means that when you assign an object to another object, say:

```
Transaction* transA = [[Transaction alloc] init];
Transaction* transB = [[Transaction alloc] init];

transB = transA;
```

The first two lines create two separate objects. But the third line assigns `transB` as a *reference* to `transA`. That is to say, they are *the same object*. Also, this leaks memory since `transB` no longer points to the original object.

While I'm not 100% sure how your object creation works, the lines similar to `[aTransaction createTransaction:n*100 ofType:cash];` are assigning the values to the same object (`aTransaction`). This means, most likely all of the objects contained within your array are pointers to the same object. Moreover, these could be leaking memory if they aren't returning autoreleased objects.

---

An easy way to log elements in an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` (or probably any collection type) is to simply do:

```
NSArray* someArray = [NSArray array];
// Add items here.
NSLog(@"SomeArray: %@", someArray);
```

The output will automatically be formatted for you.

Comment: I tried with the same as you told but its displaying some address it seems

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the objects out of the array in the last 4 lines of your code.

When you use `[transactions objectAtIndex:i]` that will return the `i'th` `transaction` object in the array.

Comment: I am putting it in a for loop so the object at index 0,1,2 whatever is the count should display.But i still could not get how to retreive the elements out of the array.